# Can't fix styles for toolbar in the action mode

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-actionmode

I can't get how to fix styles for my `Toolbar` in the action mode.

```
<!-- DialogWhenLarge uses to show Activity as Dialog on the tablet -->
    <style name="Theme.Paper.DialogWhenLarge" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DialogWhenLarge">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/Theme.Paper.Toolbar</item>
        <item name="actionBarPopupTheme">@style/Theme.Paper.Toolbar.PopupOverlay</item>
        <!-- Below attributes available on the v11+ only -->
        <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">false</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.Paper.Toolbar" parent="Theme.Paper">
        <item name="android:background">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.Paper.Toolbar.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black_87</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/black_54</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/black_30</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
        <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
    </style>
```

What is my problem in? And what do I want to get? I posted it below.

**Correct toolbar style is as I need**
[image: Correct toolbar style]
**But in action mode it looks so (white actions and a menu with primary color background and white text)**
[image: Wrong toolbar style]
P.S. I tried to fix it but each time I get wrong styles.

Answer (score 0):

I don't sure... but maybe a someone will have the same problem. So below the solution that works for me:

```
<resources>
    <!--
    *
    * App themes
    *
    -->
    <!-- DialogWhenLarge uses to show Activity as Dialog on the tablet -->
    <style name="Theme.Paper.DialogWhenLarge" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DialogWhenLarge">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="actionBarPopupTheme">@style/Theme.Paper.Toolbar.PopupOverlay</item>
        <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/Theme.Paper.ActionMode</item>
        <!-- Below attributes available on the v11+ only -->
        <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">false</item>
    </style>
    <!--
    *
    * ActionBar, AppBarLayout and Toolbar styles
    *
    -->
    <!-- Action mode -->
    <style name="Theme.Paper.ActionMode" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode">
        <item name="background">@color/primary</item>
    </style>
    <!-- Toolbar -->
    <style name="Theme.Paper.Toolbar" parent="Theme.Paper">
        <item name="android:background">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
    </style>
    <!-- Toolbar popup overlay -->
    <style name="Theme.Paper.Toolbar.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black_87</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/black_54</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/black_30</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
        <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```